# Replace expressions with their names in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have some expressions in Mathematica that are defined in terms of other expressions. I want to take some functions of the larger expression and then get the result in terms of the subexpressions.  Example:

```
In[78]:= e1 = x + y;
e2 = 2^e1;

In[80]:= D[e2, x]

Out[80]= 2^(x + y) Log[2]
```

I want the output to instead be `2^e1 Log[2]`.  I am currently using `ReplaceAll` as follows, but this is cumbersome in my actual application with about 20 subexpressions.

```
In[81]:= D[e2, x] /. e1 -> E1

Out[81]= 2^E1 Log[2]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Difficult to obtain and keep that form, if you set e1 to be x+y. So if you do not really need that, could instead work with replacement rules.

```
rul = {e1->x+y, e2->2^e1};
revrul = {x+y->e1};

InputForm[D[e2//.rul, x] /. revrul]

Out[5]//InputForm= 2^e1*Log[2]
```

Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research

Answer (score 2):

Your answer appears to be specific due to the simple form of your `e1` and `e2`. One possibility is to define `e2` as a function in terms of `e1`, without specifying what `e1` is:

```
In[8]:= Clear[e1, e2];
e2[x_] := 2^e1[x]
```

Then

```
In[10]:= D[e2[x], x]

Out[10]= 2^e1[x] Log[2] Derivative[1][e1][x]
```

which is a generally correct answer. As soon as you want it to compute, you can provide specific definition for `e1`. You can also do this inside `Block`, so that you don't introduce global definitions:

```
In[11]:= 
Block[{e1},
  e1[x_] := x + y;
  D[e2[x], x]]

Out[11]= 2^(x + y) Log[2]
```

I suppose this approach can scale to a larger number of sub-expressions.

HTH